# Flex 3: How does one access an object in an mxml file in the constructor of a class that extends it?

Tags: apache-flex

I have extended an mxml component with an actionscript class. I'm trying to access a component in the mxml file using the id (in order to add an event listener) but I cant seem to do it.

I get:

TypeError: Error #1009: Cannot access a property or method of a null object reference.

Anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Where exactly in your code are you trying to access the component? If it's before createChildren() is called, it won't exist yet.

If you're not familiar with the [flex component lifecycle](http://msimtiyaz.wordpress.com/flex/adobe-flex-component-instantiation-life-cycle/), you'll need to learn about it, it's an integral part of developing efficient flex components.

Comment: Excellent. That was the issue. I was attempting to access the component immediately after super(); but it wasnt working. Now I have put the lines into a handler, and applied it to the creationComplete event. Working perfect. Thanks!